# Conditional formatting based on multiple values and dates

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I need to format a task list based on Priority from 1 to 4 and date of completion. For example:

No formatting needed for Priority levels of 3 and 4 but if the Priority level is 1 or 2:-

and the due date is overdue it should turn the whole row red.
and the due date is no more than one week away it should turn the whole row yellow.

BUT if the progress is 100% on any of the Priority levels then it should override and turn the whole row green.

I have been using `=IF(AND` & `=IF(OR` - but I cannot get the desired results.

Due dates are in column D
Progress is in column E
Priority is in column I

Answer (score 0):

I think three rules may suit, in order set up:

for Red: `=AND(OR($F2=1,$F2=2),$D2<NOW())`
for Yellow: `=AND(OR($F2=1,$F2=2),AND($D2>NOW()),$D2<NOW()+7)`
for Green: `=$E2=1`

So Green should be applied first and for it you might as well check Stop If True. Choose a suitable range for Applies to (here `=$A$2:$F$18` in each case).

Example result:

[image: SO20272073 example]